# S3 upload progress not working properly, only one time the upload progress shows in mern

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, progress-bar

This is my nodejs code, after the file upload only one time progress get logging as 100% , not logging continues

```js
exports.uploadFile2 = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.files.file;

    const fileName = file.name;
    const parts = fileName.split(".");
    const extension = parts[parts.length - 1];

    const params = {
      Bucket: "buckname",
      Key: `${uuidv4()}.${extension}`,
      Body: file.data,
      ACL: "public-read",
      ContentEncoding: "7bit",
      ContentType: file.mimetype,
    };

    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(data.Location);

      res.json(data);
    }).on("httpUploadProgress", (p) => {
      console.log(p);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      error: "No User Found",
    });
  }
};
```

This is my react code

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { fileUploadFunction } from "../function/fileUpload";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const index = () => {
  const { auth } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleUploadFile = async (e) => {
    if (auth.token) {
      try {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          `http://localhost:5000/api/uploadFile2`,
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              authtoken: auth && auth.token,
            },
            onUploadProgress: (e) => {
              const { loaded, total } = e;
              console.log(Math.round((100 * loaded) / total));
            },
          }
        );
        // if (data) router.push(`chat/${data}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Upload file</h1>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleUploadFile} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default index;
```

In my react code , only it shows 100% ,not starting from 0 to 100, the progress is not getting continuously .

How to get progress continuesly from 0 to 100, i checked many docs, but they are providing the code , what i have.

I used only nodejs and reactjs to do this, no lambda or anything complex

Please help me to solve this, I am looking for a days

Comment: How huge is the file you were uploading?

Comment: Like 50 mb to 100 mb, but the response didn't finished, but the progress show 100%

Comment: How about the compute layer? are you running this inside a Lambda function with a Gateway infront or a Load balancer?

Comment: No lambda or anything complex, only nodejs

Comment: Did you try removing ContentEncoding: "7bit" from the params of your Node.js code?

Comment: I try, but didn't work