# How to set progress bar from 0 to 100% for each uploaded image separately

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to upload multiple images but in separate XMLHttpRequest.

The requests should executes itself sequentially (one by one) and not simultaneously.

That's because I want the progress bar to go from 0 to 100% for each uploaded image.

Using this code seems requests executes simultaneously because:

- progress bar is flickering - constantly goes back and forward
- all `finito` in console appears at the same time, i.e. at the end of entire process

If I write `ajax.open("POST", "a_pro_up.php, false")` instead of `ajax.open("POST", "a_pro_up.php");`:

- `finitos` in console appears sequentially
- but progress bar doesn't work at all

How to get fluently rising progress bar for each uploaded image separately ?

```
<input type="file" class='inpfi' id='inpimg' multiple accept="image/jpeg">
<progress class='pbar' id='pbar' value='0' max='100'> 0% </progress>

   inpimg.on('change', function(){
        var files = inpimg[0].files;
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            var file = files[i];
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('id', urw);
            fd.append('upimg', file);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", up_progress, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", up_img_finito, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "a_pro_up.php");
            ajax.send(fd);
        }
    });  

function up_progress(e){
    let percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    pbar.val(Math.round(percent));
}

function up_img_finito(){
    console.log('finito');
}
```

Comment: Yes, requests run simultaneously

Comment: By reading it, you are sending multiple file, for my case, i am sending single file, and i am not getting progress, can you help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76625377/s3-upload-progress-not-working-properly-only-one-time-the-upload-progress-shows

Comment: @Konrad - and what about progress bar. It is very ugly to see its flickering back and forward, instead of fluently for each image separatelly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to never loop ajax.

Here is a version that runs sequentially as you want

```js
let files, cnt = 0,
  max = 0;

const up_img_finito = () => {
  console.log('finito', cnt);
  cnt++
  upload();
}
const up_progress => (e) {
  let percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
  pbar.val(Math.round(percent));
};

const upload = () => {
  if (cnt >= max) {
    up_img_finito()
    return;
  }
  let file = files[i];
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('id', urw);
  fd.append('upimg', file);
  let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", up_progress, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", up_img_finito, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "a_pro_up.php");
  ajax.send(fd);
};
document.getElementById('inpimg').addEventListener('change', () => {
  files = inpimg[0].files;
  max = files.length;
  upload()
});
```